# How do I display a message in a jQuery Mobile ListView when empty?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I want to show a message when a jQuery mobile ListView has no elements. For example: "There are no elements." How can I do it?

Comment: A listview that is dynamically generated? or a listview that uses filtering?

Comment: @andleer a list view that is dynamically generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a popup to show warning:

```
$('#index').live('pagebeforeshow',function(e,data){   
    if($('#test-list li').length === 0){
        setTimeout(function(){$('#MyFirstPopup').popup('open');},100);
    }
});
```

Here's an working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/wy5R3/

Answer (score 2):

If you are dynamically generating your listview and find no rows to display, why not simply display a row with a message stating as much?

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
    <li data-role="list-divider">Results</li>
    <li>No records found</li>
</ul>
```

http://jsbin.com/eyozis/1/edit